# Can I augment all DU types with a method that can access the type itself, in F#?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I am trying to define an DU where I can query the actual type to perform some operations based on the name. This is used to build string ids where the name of the DU type is used.

for example:

```
type MyDU =
    | TypeA
    | TypeB

    member this.DoSomething =
        printfn "I am of type %s" (this.SomehowGetTheTypeName)
```

then do:

```
let a = MyDU.TypeA
a.DoSomething
```

to get:

> "I am of type TypeA"

Comment: Doesn't `typeof<MyDU>.Name` work?

Comment: the issue seems to be that if I do: type MyDU = | TypeA of <something>.. etc I can do it and, get the type of 'this', but when the types are  just declared like enums, it doesn't work

Comment: `printfn "%A" this` will print the case. Note that you say "type", but you refer to `TypeA`, these are cases of the type, not the type itself, which here is `MyDU`. `%A` will print that case, here `TypeA`.

Comment: ok, I got it! it works; thanks!